# AutoLayout Equal Heights hides Subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a UIView buttonView and gave it an equal heights constraint to the super UIView with a 0.4 multiplier. The frame is adjusted correctly but the subviews of buttonView are not visible. However, when I click on the position where the buttons are supposed to be then the actions triggers.
This does not happen when I change the buttonViews constraint to be a fixed height.
I can get more into details if you want but has anyone run into something similar?

**EDIT**

[image: That's the custom view][image: Custom View in simulator]

There should be two buttons where the white space underneath the label is. When I click on the white space the timer runs but the button is not visible.

Comment: post your constraint and problem image

Comment: Not getting your problem exactly. provide more details

Comment: Provide the snap of inspector side also.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: Is it possible to post the actual Xcode project or at least that part of it?  I haven't encountered this issue before and seeing / running the full storyboard would help

Comment: Thanks for posting the sample project.  Do you have a version that is showing the issue you are describing in your question?  I changed your "Button Record View" constraints in the sample project to be a 0.4 proportional height to its superview and I still see its button subview.  http://d.pr/i/1bOvl

Comment: I want the Record Button View width to be 50% of the width of its superview. I also then want to height to be the width. The button inside the view should just fill the view. I can click on the button but I can't figure out why it's not visible

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at the project and the issue I saw in a couple places was that auto layout and manual frame transformations are both used, which can be tricky.  A couple specific things I saw that you will probably need to modify in order for the view to adapt and render correctly at different sizes / orientations:

1) The CustomAudioLearn view loads a view from a xib and adds it as a subview. However, it does not set constraints on this subview to make sure that the subview always hugs the edges of the parent view.  So changing the size of the CustomAudioLearn view through auto layout in the storyboard results in the the xib-based subview always staying the same size.  You should either add constraints to the subview or override `layoutSubviews()` in CustomAudioLearn and include `self.customView.frame = self.bounds` and `self.customViw.layoutIfNeeded()` in there.  Also, I would suggest removing the line `self.customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

2) Similarly, the `RecordButtonView` sets its corner radius on `awakeFromNib()`, but after layout happens, that's no longer the right radius. So you should again consider overriding `layoutSubviews()` or similar location to adjust the radius every time the layout is updated.

3) Lastly, the superview of the RecordButtonView in the storyboard is set to a height constraint of 70 with a priority of 1000.  If you want the RecordButtonView to expand for the space available, you should reduce the priority of that height constraint so that the proportional width of the RecrodButtonView and the 1:1 aspect ratio take priority in determining the height of the superview.  Otherwise, it will always be 70 points, or there will be conflicting constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I set the rounded corners to half of my frame's width. The radius got so big that it completely hide the view. I changed it so that after the bounds are set I change the corner radius. Sorry for confusion but thanks for any help!